# Dart Sip Ua va Call Keep flutter vs Flutter_webrtc

Tags: flutter, webrtc, react-native-webrtc, flutter-webrtc

I am familiar with webrtc and worked with it before. [callkeep](https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/callkeep) service can be used for managing calling states in mobile application but then what is the use case of [dart-sip-ua](https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/dart-sip-ua/issues?). The documentation is not sufficient to distinguish between them

By the way thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make class `A implements SipUaHelperListener`
After that, you `@override` the functions in this class
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JtKl.jpg)